# How to pass parameter via ng-view to corresponding route in AngularJS SPA?

Tags: angularjs

I have angular SPA with routing defined, main page is basically like this:

```
<ng-view></ng-view>
```

As you know partial templates through routing will be loaded into `<ng-view>`

Now, I need to pass a parameter `wonum` (Work Order Number) for each route.

I want to know if its possible to assign `wonum` as an attribute to `<ng-view>` and be able to access this param, like this:

```
<ng-view wonum="BRK18482020">
```

**Any way this could be accomplished ??**

When the page first loaded, `wonum` param comes as URL parameter:

http://localhost/RealSuiteApps/RealHelp/-1/Detail/?wonum=BRK18482020

Now,

when partial templates are loaded into `<ng-view>`, this `wonum` parameter is no longer available in URL. The question is - how can I make `wonum` parameter available for each route?

I tried to add `wonum` parameter to the routing, like this:

```
        .when("/:wonum", { templateUrl: "Template?name=Main", controller: "DetailController", controllerAs: "vm" })
        .when("/ServiceProvider:wonum", { templateUrl: "Template?name=ServiceProvider", controller: "DetailController", controllerAs: "vm" })
        .when("/AssetGroup:wonum", { templateUrl: "Template?name=AssetGroup", controller: "DetailController", controllerAs: "vm" })
```

How do I actually pass a value here?
And how can I read that param?

Another option of which I was asking - is it possible to assign this param to `ng-view` as an attribute and then read it in my angular controller ?

Comment: Where will this `wonum` be coming from ? Can you use `/myroute/:wonum` or something in your route definition ?

Comment: where does that value come from? Services are there to share data across app. Or as mentioned put it into routing? This is definitely an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: On a first load its comming as url param, after the page is loaded it bocomes a SPA based on angular routing, however it disappears from url, I defined default route as 

.when("/:wonum", { templateUrl: "Template?name=Main", controller: "DetailController", controllerAs: "vm" })

Comment: Can store it in a service. But if it's required in other controllers you would have to handle some sort of redirect if it doesn't exist either using `resolve` or from the service. If app is young would be much simpler if you were able to switch to ui-router and nest all routes that depend on that number under a parent. The one resolve would block all child routes

Comment: updated the question with more info